# Can't see nodemon console changes and logs when using lerna

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, lerna, monorepo

[image]

As you see it starts the node express app and the react app but no logs. how can I fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Try to pass the `--stream` parameters to the command `lerna run`. From the docs

> Stream output from child processes immediately, prefixed with the originating package name. This allows output from different packages to be interleaved.

Comment: this should be voted as the right answer.